# Is ROA a specific form of doing SOA?

Tags: architecture, web-services, rest, soa, soap

I have read somewhere that ROA (Resource Oriented Architecture) is SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) with specific constraints added. SOA is the abstract concept of combining discrete pieces of software and ROA is an implementation of SOA with all of the constraints of RESTful services applied to it:

> SOA = the concept
>
> ROA = the concept + specific implementation details

I also had my share of posts saying that ROA is different than SOA, then simply fallback to statements like "ROA is REST" and "SOA is SOAP" and presenting the same more or less pertinent comparisons and differences between SOAP and REST.

So just to clear up my confusion: **Is ROA a specific form of doing SOA?**

Comment: Since nobody can define SOA beyond buzz words, answering your question is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOA is by definition independent of any technology. SOA can be implemented using any service-based technology, it obviously encompasses all REST/HTTP applications.
Based on this, ROA might be considered as a subpart of SOA that respects a specific set of guidelines of an implementation of the REST-style architecture.